# How to Save the Command Output to a File in Json using azure cli

Tags: azure-cli

How to save output of a script in json file using az cli .
I am using

```
>>config.json
```

but I want to use something else

Comment: what is meant by "something else"?

Comment: (Out-File -FilePath )     
This is one way but it is not working properly, I am not getting all the resources only few resources are getting displayed